# Cannot deploy to Firebase due to .env file

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

When trying to deploy to Firebase (this case Firebase Functions) I'm getting this error:

```
Error: Failed to load environment variables from .env.:
- Error Key FIREBASE_TOKEN starts with a reserved prefix (X_GOOGLE_ FIREBASE_ EXT_)
error Command failed with exit code 2.
```

And I actually have an .env file in the functions directory.

And I need to keep the variable name because it's used in different parts of the application.

How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, I need to have FIREBASE_TOKEN within my environment variables in a .env file because my development environment is within a Docker Container and I don't want to "firebase login" each time the container rebuilds.

So in order to deploy the solution I use dotenv and cross-var packages, and have the script like this:

```
"deploy": "dotenv -e ../.env cross-var firebase deploy --only functions --token %FIREBASE_TOKEN%",
```

What I did was to move the .env file to the upper level (root of the project) and reference it in the dotenv command with the -e flag to specify the location of the file.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I moved `.env` file to main root directory of the project instead of `functions` folder and it worked fine right after. see the answer [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/5219#issuecomment-1472756674) as well.